# Database Project Over Multiple Environments?

Tags: database, database-schema, release-management, ms-release-management, dacpac

How can you have environment specific table values in your database project and make sure that they only deploy to the environment you are deploying to with Release Management?  We have been using Release Management for some time now, but only for .NET code.  We are somewhat new to the DACPAC realm, but have found it easy to set up and use via release management.  However, now we want to extend this capability to a table that has configuration variables per environment.  How do we make this part of our database project and make sure that each environment has its own unique version of data?

Answer (score 1):

Use SSDT for publishing the database schema and reference data; don't use it to manage environment settings.

Personally, I would (and have) run a secondary script post-deployment that configured environment-specific values. This is no different than putting the correct values in the web.config file of a web application post-deployment. It's something you manage within your deployment tool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  In our instance, we have specific fields in our database that point to environmental specific locations (UNC paths) and/or client specific information that differs from TEST to PROD; urls and/or ids not controlled by our system.  So our challenge was how to run a post-deployment script specific to each environment.  As you will see by the other answer we ended up discovering SQL Command Variables in combination with publish profiles to help us determine which scripts to run.

Comment: The problem we run into is that SSDT wants to 'fix' all those users/role assignments that aren't in your project.  We don't want those in the project though because they shouldn't be in production.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the release management part to the question (because it depends what mode you use and whether you store configuration variables in RM etc) you can certainly pass in environment specific values into your dacpac execution (for use in 'postdeploy' data scripts) using sqlcmd variables defined in a tokenised publish file.
Broadly the process is:

- Use standard sqlcmdvar syntax in your post deploy script e.g insert into table values '$(my_env_var)'
- update the database project properties (sqlcmd tab) to include your new variable which ensures your dacpac expects a value when executed
- Generate a publish.xml file (which should now include a  node)
- create a publish.release.xml file which contains transform instructions to update the value of your  node to introduce a token e.g. ##my_env_var##
- update your database project file(.sqlproj) to include instructions to transform publish.xml on build using the contents of publish.release.xml

Its quite long winded but what you get out of the above is a dacapac + tokenised publish file in your build output ready to be detokenised and executed by your deployment process..be that RM or any other tool.

Comment: Thanks.  This is basically what I ended up figuring out after posting this yesterday.  The key was figuring out how to use the SQL Command Variables that can be set in combination with publish files.  I've given you an up vote but am too new to Stack Overflow for it to show up publicly.